# Change URL ID into simple text

Tags: php, url, seo

I'm trying to change that.

For example, upon submitting the URL http://www.fxstoc.com/detailed_news.php?newsid=25 I want to return http://www.fxstoc.com/serbia-holds-main-rate-as-vucic-Prepares-to-Form-new-government

I like to replace newsid=25 to simple text
How is this possible with php?

Comment: mod_rewrite and a mvc type router

Comment: you mean like in wordpress(blog.com/post-name)?

Comment: No, its php site not CMS

Answer (score 3):

You need `mod_rewrite`. It's an Apache function that transforms for example `detailed_news.php?newsid=25` to `serbia-holds-main-rate-as-vucic-Prepares-to-Form-new-government`.

Look here some examples:

http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule http://www.fxstoc.com/detailed_news/(.*)/(.*)/$ /detailed_news.php?$1=$2

Comment: i think it should be `RewriteRule fxstoc.com/(.*)/$ /detailed_news.php?newsid=$2` but im not sure. i didnt worked with this yet.